# BitArray doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, .net, bitarray

I have this BitArray  :

```
    BitArray bits = new BitArray(2);
    bits[0] = false;
    bits[1] = true;
```

Which represents :  `10b` --> 2

Let's see what's its value :

```
  int[] array = new int[1];
  bits.CopyTo(array, 0);
  Console.WriteLine(array[0]);  // value=2
```

Great.

Now I'm changing the first code to :

```
   bool[] bits = new bool[2] {  false, true }; //same value !
   BitArray myBA4 = new BitArray( bits );

   //and again...
   int[] array = new int[1];
   bits.CopyTo(array, 0);
   Console.WriteLine(array[0]);
```

- Exception  : *Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.*

**Question**

Where is my mistake ? I think it should be same result.

Comment: Are you sure you meant `bits.CopyTo(...)` and not `myBA4.CopyTo(...)`?

Comment: @Michael omg ,My bad . sorry you're right. now working as expected. ( too late)...copy pasted badly....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool[] bits = new bool[2] { false, true };
```

allocates an array of two elements, and `CopyTo` is supposed to copy them one by one. It cannot succeed because

- the second array is too short;
- `bool` cannot be converted to `int` implicitly.

Comment: got confused with the variable. tnx

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yep, `CopyTo` copies a _range of elements_. BTW, with `int[2]` it would be another exception, since `bool` cannot be converted to `int`.

Comment: Yes checked : (_Source array type cannot be assigned to destination array type._).